# 'Ordered' + object + past participle

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice, past-participles, omissibility

[Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage, page 852](https://books.google.es/books?id=w1WuDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA582&dq=The%20construction%20ordered%20%2B%20object%20%2B%20past%20participle%20(often%20expressed%20in%20the%20passive)%20is%20first%20recorded%20in%201781%20in%20AmE%20(%20These%20things%20were%20ordered%20delivered%20to%20the%20army%E2%80%94J.%20Witherspoon)%20and%20has%20been%20predominantly%20American%20ever%20since%3A%20BrE%20normally%20requires%20the%20insertion%20of%20to%20be%20before%20the%20past%20participle.&hl=es&pg=PA582#v=onepage&q=The%20construction%20ordered%20%20%20object%20%20%20past%20participle%20(often%20expressed%20in%20the%20passive)%20is%20first%20recorded%20in%201781%20in%20AmE%20(%20These%20things%20were%20ordered%20delivered%20to%20the%20army%E2%80%94J.%20Witherspoon)%20and%20has%20been%20predominantly%20American%20ever%20since:%20BrE%20normally%20requires%20the%20insertion%20of%20to%20be%20before%20the%20past%20participle.&f=false) reads

> The construction *ordered* + object + past participle (often expressed
> in the passive) is first recorded in 1781 in AmE ( *These things were
> **ordered delivered** to the army*—J. Witherspoon). BrE normally requires
> the insertion of *to be* before the past participle.

[OED reads](https://oed.com/oed2/00164588): *Also with ellipsis of 'to be' (chiefly U.S.)*, but every example is in the form [*ordered*](https://oed.com/oed2/00164588) too.

What is the reason behind this structure of ? I cannot recall anything similar in grammatical terms.

Comment: As the OED says, in the active voice it can be "ordered" + object + complement, meaning to order something to be in such a state. In your example, "delivered" is acting as an adjective, as a past participle often does. This isn't unique to "order": "keep", "got", and other common verbs can be used the same way "to keep something organised", "we got him organised", etc. But these are just observations, not reasons; I'm not sure how you would find out why this construction was first used.

Comment: _I ordered this steak broiled, not boiled!_

Comment: @Stuart F How then do you explain the parallel 'They ordered these things be delivered to the army'? It's a verbal usage, as in 'He ordered them shot'; 'He had/got the car fixed'. Complex catenation.